# How to update progress bar using checkboxes on different page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to update a progress bar value using check boxes. The idea is check boxes and progress bar on different pages. when I check the checkbox on page 1 it will update the progress bar value on another page. I am really stuck. Tried every possible thing. Help me!!!

This is my code:

Review-order.html

```
    <div class="progress">
         <p><progress id="avancement" value="0" max="100"></progress></p>
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
       </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $('.progressbar_chkbox').click(function() {
        var progress = sessionStorage.getItem("progress");
       $('#avancement').val(progress);
      });

    });

    </script>
```

Notification.php

```
    <div class="c-content-panel">
         <?php
           $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))   
             {
          ?>
         <div class="c-body">
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"> This issue has been reported by <?php echo $row['your_name']; ?> from  <?php echo $row['store_name']; ?>
             <p> <?php echo $row['issue_title']; ?></p>
             <p><?php echo $row['file'] ?></p>
             <p><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">View File </a></p>
             <a class="c-font-slim" href="#">read this important alert message</a>.
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div> 
          <div class="c-content-panel">

            <div class="c-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-body"> 
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Action</label>
                              <form action="track.php" method="post">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="progressbar_chkbox"  type="checkbox" id="pending" onclick="send();" data-progress="20" value="pending">Pending </label>
                                   <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                   <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" class="progressbar_chkbox" id="read" type="checkbox" onclick="send();" data-progress="40" value="option2" value="read"> Read</label>
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" class="progressbar_chkbox" id="completed" type="checkbox" onclick="send();" data-progress="80" value="option3" name="completed"> Completed </label>
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme c-btn-square" onclick="send();">
                                        Submit</button>
                         </div>
                       </form> 
                     </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
 </div>

   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

 <?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

          $('.progressbar_chkbox').click(function() {

            var progress = $(this).data('progress');

            sessionStorage.setItem("progress", progress)

          });

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Maybe using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), or [sse's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: @mplungjan: both pages are from the same origin. But still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using sessionStorage. You need to use localStorage. That should work if the pages are from the same origin - You however do not HAVE a $('.progressbar_chkbox') on the other page so you would need to check the storage using setInterval

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/288hvkc2/) since SO does not allow sessionStorage/localStorage

```
var tId;
$(function() {
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    var progress = localStorage.getItem("progress");
    $('#avancement').val(progress);
  },1000);
});
```

Have a look at

http://plungjan.name/SO/progress/page1.html
http://plungjan.name/SO/progress/page2.html

Comment: No, Both answers are not working. Progressbar is still blank – 
Is there any problem with button click from Notification.php?

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle. If the pages are on the same origin then it should work

Comment: Just checked the fiddle. Strange it is working on fiddle but not on localhost

Comment: Fixed it. You need localstorage. Session storage is for one page only - see update

Comment: Also move the `onclick="send();" ` to the click handler

Comment: Also make them radios?

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot. One simple question. when I upload it on the server it will work as it is now? or do I have to do any changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152007/discussion-between-user8380237-and-mplungjan).